# Closing a window opened by AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlExtender

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<div id="id1" runat="server">Open Windows</div>
<AjaxControlToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server" TargetControlID="id1" PopupControlID="Panel1" Position="Top"  />

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<div> this text will show in the window that will open when the user clicks on 'OpenWindow' </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

How do I get a reference to the window that will open and then close it?

Comment: this is the code I am trying to use (I posted the code but it is not showing on this form)<div id="id1" runat="server">Open Windows</div>

<AjaxControlToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server" TargetControlID="id1" PopupControlID="Panel1" Position="Top"  />

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<div> this text will show in the window that will open when the user clicks on 'OpenWindow' </div>
</asp:Panel>

Answer (score 1):

To open and close the window from the main window, assign your command to a variable.

```
var newWindow = window.open("...");

// do something

newWindow.close();
```

Or if you are needing the new window to close via a link in the new window, try something like:

```
<a href="self.close()">Close</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I name all of the windows that I open, then if I want to close it I have a file close.html that basically has

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">self.close()</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then whenever I want to kill an open window, if I know the name, I can call:

```
window.open(<window name>, 'close.html');
```

A little hacky, but it works - especially if you're only using one window at a time.